# having issues calling a method in java

Tags: java, jsf

a simple question but i litterally can not remember, basically i want to run java methods in an certain order, i did have it working perfectly, but i have had to add something to the start and now it will not run in order

Basically before was this code,

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {


        //System.out.println(destinationPDF);
        //System.out.println(destination);

// Get the username from the login page, this is used to create a folder for each user
        System.out.println("called get username");
        username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    }

    public void File() {
        File theFile = new File(destination + username); // will create a sub folder for each user (currently does not work, below hopefully is a solution)
        theFile.mkdirs();
        System.out.println("Completed File");
    }
```

it would run and automatically call the next required method, it would call them in this order :

```
INFO: buttonToUploadText invoked
INFO: called get username
INFO: called handle file
INFO: Completed Creation of folder
INFO: Now in copying of file proccess
INFO: Completed Creation of folder for copy of PDF
INFO: End of copying file creation
INFO: Called CopyFile
INFO: New file created!
INFO: Copying is now happening
```

But i have added a new method, that calls variables from a file :

```
@PostConstruct
    public void loadProp() {
        System.out.println("Loading properties");
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"); //points to a properties file, this will load up destinations instead of having to declare them here
        try {
            configProp.load(in);
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destination"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("fileList"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This now must run first when it is triggered in order to declare variables, however now it will now run public void int() once complete instead it skips a lot and runs     public void handleFileUpload

so what is the best way of calling public void init() from public void loadProp() {

Edit 2:

```
    private Properties configProp = new Properties();

    public void loadProp() {
        System.out.println("Loading properties");
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"); //points to a properties file, this will load up destinations instead of having to declare them here
        try {
            configProp.load(in);
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destination"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("fileList"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private String destinationPDF = configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF");
    public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
    private String username;
    //public static String destination = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/uploaded/"; // main location for uploads//TORNADO ONLY //"D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/uploaded/"; // USE ON PREDATOR ONLY 
    public static String NewDestination;
    public static String UploadedfileName;
    public static String CompletefileName;
    //
    //Strings for file copy
    //
    //private String destinationPDF = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/"; //USE ON TORNADO//"D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/";//USE ON PREDATOR    
    private String NewdestinationPDF;
    public static String PdfLocationViewable;

    //
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

       FileUploadController.loadProp();

        //System.out.println(destinationPDF);
        //System.out.println(destination);

// Get the username from the login page, this is used to create a folder for each user
        System.out.println("called get username");
        username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    }
```

Comment: Hub?  If you want to run two methods one after the other, then just call them one after the other...

Comment: I think we're missing some context here. How are you calling these methods? What kind of class (or classes) are you working with? Why would it run in any order now? If you have more code, you should post it; if not, there's your problem.

Comment: Sorry, have added more details should have added it in the first place, basically i have added a new method to run first and now can not get the other methods to follow in the order they were before i added this method

Comment: Why didn't you just add the `loadProps` method as the first all in `init`? You've changed your @PostConstruct handler, effectively changing the behavior that occurred when your bean is loaded.

Comment: You shall have only one method annotated with `PostConstruct`, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Comment: yes sorry the `PostConstruct` i move when i add the loadProps to make this run first, i have tried to call loadProps from init but i get the error non-static method loadProp() can not be refrenced from static contex

Comment: That error doesn't make sense, neither of your `loadProps` or `init` method are static. Post the version of the code where you were calling `loadProps` inside of the `init` method.

Comment: added to the above edit

Comment: Your trying to call the `loadProp` method statically, but ***its not static***. You should simply call `loadProp` (if `FileUploadController` is a separate class you should inject it into the class with the @PostConstruct annotation).

Comment: Thanks i managed to solve it, needed to take a break !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should have only one `@PostConstruct` method.

Replace

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadProp() {
    // ...
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // ...
}
```

By

```
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {
    loadProp();
    init();
}

private void loadProp() {
    // ...
}

private void init() {
    // ...
}
```

*(I'd only consider renaming `postConstruct()` to `init()` and rename the original `init()` to something else matching its actual job)*